# How to merge street layers in QGIS for exporting to PostGIS?

Tags: python, qgis

Is there any way of merging lots of street data in QGIS and getting one layer for exporting it to Postgresql?  I know one method using mmqgis "Merge Layer" tool.  It works in Ubuntu but not in Windows. When I want to open my MapInfo .TAB file in Windows it opens but this time mmgqis tools do not work.  In Ubuntu it gives "***.TAB is not a valid or recognized data source "...

Can I solve this with some Python code or any other way?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Aragon N. Please consider starting to accept answers to your questions if they helped you solve your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMqgis is a 3rd party plugin, you may want to try the Merge tool in the vector menu. You have also a Merge tool in the digitizing toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just doing this to load the data into PostGIS later, you might instead use Postgis Manager plugin for QGIS which allows you to load Shapefiles into tables either creating a new table or appending the data to an existing table:

[image]

If you are looking for a script solution, I'd suggest using shp2pgsql. That's the same thing Postgis Manager is using in the background.